# Integrating Neteller to my Asp.net website

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I am banging my head for 2 days to integrate neteller into my website but could not get it,
Returned response in xml contain error saying Invalid merchantid/merchant key ,how can i get them?

```
<form method="post" action="https://test.api.neteller.com/netdirect">
   <input type="text" name="version" value=" 4.1">
<input type="text" name="amount" size="10" value="3443" maxlength="10">
<input type="text" name="currency" value="USD" size="10" maxlength="3">
<input type="text" name="net_account" size="20" value="" maxlength="100">
<input type="text" name="secure_id" size="10" value="" maxlength="6">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="43646">
<input type="hidden" name="merch_key" value="456453">
<input type="hidden" name="merch_transid" value="46436436" maxlength="50">
<input type="hidden" name="language_code" value="EN">
<input type="hidden" name="merch_name" value="fdghdfhgf">
<input type="hidden" name="merch_account" value="436346" maxlength="50">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_1" value="test123" maxlength="50">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_2" value="test123" maxlength="50">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_3" value="test123" maxlength="50">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Make Transfer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Neteller is Neteller Payment Gateway

Comment: You might want to consider using an API wrapper instead https://github.com/Sire/neteller-rest-api (Did not exist when question was posted).

Answer (score 0):

At first You should not put your merchant credentials in hidden inputs for security reasons. Everyone can see your sensitive data. Make a POST on server side not client side.

merchant API key You can generate on merchant neteller panel in the Developer tab.